# What regiments of the British East India Company were in southeastern India in the late 1790s?

Tags: military, india, british-empire, imperialism, chartered-companies

I have been researching ranks and positions that existed in various regiments and civil branches of the British East India Company during the late 1790s to early 1800s. Those aren't as hard as finding names of actual regiments, divisions, and units that moved along the southeast coast of India during the 1790s, which is what I'm asking about here. Many of the listings shown were in later 1800s and were shown to be companies that merged with the British Army.

I understand that the major branches were Madras, Bengal, and Bombay, and they dispatched smaller units to protect BEIC interests which were won from the French or the natives. I found a few of those.

Bonus points: In this same vein, were there any local forces in Visakhapatnam or Andhra Pradesh that had a particular name for its unit during the 18th century? Or is it true that these local forces didn't really have a military name?

Comment: One of the key problems, as can be seen in quick glance down the list on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Honourable_East_India_Company_regiments), is that their (native) regiments changed names quite often in the second half of the 18th century.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete list of all regiments, or just some examples of what the regiments were called? If the latter, the wikipedia link supplied by @SteveBird would seem to be a complete answer.

Comment: @SteveBird: Yes, that's a definite issue I kept running into.

Comment: @Semaphore: I'm looking for specific regiments in southeast region of the India subcontinent, mostly in the 1790s. I found names that referred to the divisions that were in the 1800s and could track some of them to earlier versions, but they had nothing to do with southeast region.